# Alterar logo apenas do Footer

Tags: wordpress

Estou utilizando um tema que tem como padrão a memas logo para o header  e para o footer, queria alterar apenas a logo do footer,a baixo o  código atual referente a logo do footer.

```
        <a class="brand pull-left" href="<?php
        echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">

            <?php
            $logo = get_theme_mod( 'bauhaus_logo_small' );
            $logo_text = get_theme_mod( 'bauhaus_logo_text' );
            $logo_name = get_theme_mod( 'bauhaus_logo_name' );
            if ( isset( $logo{2} ) ) {
                ?>
                <img alt="" src="<?php echo esc_url( $logo ); ?>">
                <div class="brand-info">
                    <div class="brand-name"><?php if ( isset( $logo_name{0} ) ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( $logo_name );
                        } ?></div>
                    <div class="brand-text"><?php if ( isset( $logo_text{0} ) ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( $logo_text );
                        } ?></div>
                </div>

                <?php
```

Comment: Pq que dentro desse SRC `<img alt="" src="<?php echo esc_url( $logo ); ?>">` vc não coloca o caminho da sua logo na mão mesmo tipo `<img alt="" src="img/logo-footer.png">`?

Answer (score 0):

Basta você editar o logo em `<img alt="" src="<?php echo esc_url( $logo ); ?>">`, pode trocar `<?php echo esc_url( $logo ); ?>` pelo caminho da imagem que você quer, ou se é apenas o tamanho da imagem, você pode corrigir por CSS.